# Pivot table sum on condition

Tags: sql-server, pivot

One of the stored procedure in my project is giving the following data which has been stored in a table "tblSourceData":

```
Month       MonthNo   Year  Type        Supplier Name   SupplierType    Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
April       4         2021   Pending    Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
May         5         2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       4
June        6         2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
July        7         2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
August      8         2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       2
September   9         2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       3
October     10        2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
November    11        2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
November    11        2021   Contracted Supplier-2      Shipping Line       2
November    11        2021   Pending    Supplier-2      Shipping Line       1
December    12        2021   Contracted Supplier-1      Shipping Line       1
December    12        2021   Contracted Supplier-2      Shipping Line       2
December    12        2021   Pending    Supplier-2      Shipping Line       2
```

The 3 possible values for column "Type" above are "Contracted", "NonContracted" and "Pending".

I want to product the following output:

```
Supplier Name   SupplierType    Month      Year Contracted  Non-Contracted  Pending Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   April      2021     0              0    1   1
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   May        2021     4              0    0   4
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   June       2021     1              0    0   1
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   July       2021     1              0    0   1
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   August     2021     2              0    0   2
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   September  2021     3              0    0   3
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   October    2021     1              0    0   1
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   November   2021     1              0    0   1
Supplier-2      Shipping Line   November   2021     2              0    1   3
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   December   2021     1              0    0   1
Supplier-2      Shipping Line   December   2021     2              0    2   4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grand Total                                         18             0    4   22
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried the following query but it is not producing the desired output:

```
SELECT [Supplier Name],SupplierType, [Month], [Year],
[Contracted]=isnull([Contracted],0), [NonContracted]=isnull([NonContracted],0), [Pending]=isnull([Pending],0) 
FROM  
    (select [Supplier Name],SupplierType, [Month],MonthNo, [Year],[Type],[Count] from tblSourceData) AS tab  
PIVOT  
(  
    sum([Count])  
    FOR [Type] IN ([Contracted],[NonContracted],[Pending])  
) AS Tab2  
order by MonthNo
```

It is giving the following output:

```
Supplier Name   SupplierType    Month      Year Contracted  Non-Contracted  Pending Total
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   April      2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   May        2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   June       2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   July       2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   August     2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   September  2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   October    2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   November   2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-2      Shipping Line   November   2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-1      Shipping Line   December   2021     0              0    0   0
Supplier-2      Shipping Line   December   2021     0              0    0   0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Grand Total                                         0              0    0   0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The information above may have been misaligned. Pardon me on this.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

EDIT: I have replaced the images of the data by its text representation.

Comment: Please do not post images of data, instead please post them as text. Please reserve images for things which cannot be easily represented as text.

Comment: Where do you propose to get `SupplierName` from? Also your query doesn't match your image

Comment: @Charlieface I have edited my question above. You may have a look now.

Comment: @Charlieface.. I am getting `SupplierName` from "tblSourceData" which is created by a stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your result, I get your expected result https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d54c1c556a892a7cb3bc09162a740e3a. Do you need the Grand Total row in SQL? If so you should probably switch to conditional aggregation and use `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS`

Comment: @Charlieface.. it worked.. thanks for your help.. I also managed to get the grand total row.